# Error 1004 when trying to sort on key, sort reference not valid

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this sort, I am receiving the following error:

"Run-time Error '1004':

The Sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort BY box isn't the same or blank"

I had it running just find earlier, and have been testing a sub on the same data, I haven't changed anything but adding the xlheader option to yes. I have tried removing the header option to get the range working with no result.

I have tried defining the range specifically ("A:AL"), yet it still does not work for sht3 as it does for sht2

```
'Dim sht2 as worksheet, sht3 as worksheet

Set sht2 = thiswb.Sheets("Tracking Report")
Set sht3 = thiswb.Sheets("New Extract")

    'sorting block
        With sht3.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            'secondary here
            .Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Key2:=Range("C1"), Header:=xlYes
            'priority here
            .Sort Key1:=Range("M1"), Key2:=Range("D1"), Key3:=Range("I1"), Header:=xlYes
        End With
        With sht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        'Errors on next line
            .Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Key2:=Range("C1"), Header:=xlYes
            .Sort Key1:=Range("M1"), Key2:=Range("D1"), Key3:=Range("I1"), Header:=xlYes
        End With
```

Comment: These unqualified ranges - `Key2:=Range("C1")` refer the whatever sheet is active at the time. Is that your intent? If not, qualify them with the sheet they are on.

Comment: Silly me forgetting basic stuff, thank you!